# How to add appointment with specify organizer via EWS?

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, appointment

How I can add appointment to Exchange calendar and specify organizer to this appointment?

I work with calendar via EWS (Exchange Web Service) from C# code.

`Organizer` field in class `Appointment` have only get() method.
I found info about way via [ImpersonatedUserId](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb204095(exchg.140).aspx), but this function don't work in new version of Exchange Server.

Comment: Impersonation works on all versions of Exchange from 2007 I would suggestion you check your configuration if its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the organizer is set by Exchange based on the credentials presented when the appointment is made.  Using impersonation may allow you to appear to Exchange like a particular user, and it has other benefits as well in terms of throttling, but that permission has to be assigned in advance via PowerShell.

Comment: Our security department don't allow this :( I need find another way, if it possible...